# what is the equivalent in windows phone 7 c# for the android library project?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, library-project

i am new to windows phone 7 programming, I've been developing for android, i have developed an application using a library project in android and reference it in my client applications.
my question is: is there any thing equvalent to alibrary project in windows phone 7?
thaks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create library projects in Windows Phone and share them between several applications. Just click on the solution: Add -> New project -> Windows Phone Class Library

Answer (score 0):

This will help u more in mapping apis from android to WP7
**http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Library**